# Adding certain values from vector to vector

Tags: r, vector

I'm just starting with R. I have to vectors, `d` and `vast`. `d` has 1000 values, each between 0-100. I have to add values that are <30 from `d` to `vast` in same order as they are in `d`. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
vast = c()
for(i in d){
  if(d[i]<30){
    vast <- c(vast, d[i])
  }
}
```

If I print out `vast` it seems to have all needed values, but it isn't accepted. Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there easier ways to achieve this?

Comment: Just `vast <- d[d < 30]` isn't it? If you ever find yourself writing a loop for something that should be straightforward in R, stop. Chances are there's a way to do it without a loop.

Comment: Shortest might be `d[d<30]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in d){
```

The above is the problem. You should use following instead

```
for(i in 1:length(d)){
```

Let's say d starts with 40,20,6. You are adding the numbers in the wrong order, because you're looking at `d[40]`, then `d[20]`, etc. If you use `1:length(d)` you will scan your vector in the correct order.